# UrlRedirect - IIS6 - PHP -> .NET

Tags: php, asp.net, windows, iis-6, windows-server-2003

I am looking to move an existing WordPress installation to a custom platform comprised of a .net based blog as well as other new functionality/modules on the site running under IIS6/Win2k3.  There are several thousand posts in the existing WordPress site that have been migrated to the new database structure, however, I'd like to preserve the old urls (for search engine sake).

The application is already using URLRewriting.NET to provide SEO friendly links throughout the site, so I know I can write up a rule to parse/redirect the inbound requests:

http://mydomain.com/index.php/2008/11/20/my-post/

Would be handled by something like:
http://mydomain.com/blog.aspx?slug=my-post&date=2008-11-20

To do it this way, I would need to configure the .php extension to be handled by aspnet_isapi.dll.  Is it possible to have one 'Web Site' configured to handle PHP via aspnet and another 'Web Site' configured to handle PHP using the actual php isapi handler?  It would seem possible based on the configuration through IIS Manager, though I suspect the whole 'Web Service Extension' bit would cause a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to change handler's based on the site.